# How to automatically create a WPF data input form based on data source?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In the old VB6 days we had a database form wizard. You could just select a database, selected the fields to include and it laid out the textboxes and labels automatically and also did the databinding.

I have not been able to find an equivalent in WPF. What I would like to do is to drag and drop a table from my edmx file to my XAML designer window and have fields generated and laid out nicely.

The Customer table in the **AdventureWorks** database for example has more than a dozen fields. Rather than laying them all out myself, isn't there a wizard to make my life easy? Or maybe a 3rd party tool that you use to do the same?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Server Explorer`, select the database -> select the table/field and drag it to the form and the should get you what your after.